# C++ singleton GetInstance() return

Tags: c++, reference, singleton, pointers

When implementing a singleton in C++, is it better for GetInstance() to return a pointer to the singleton object, or a reference? Does it really matter?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I prefer a reference. I use reference instead of a pointer whenever I want to document that:

- It can't be null
- It won't be changed (to point to something else)
- It mustn't be deleted

Comment: As Dmitriy Matveev pointed out below: don't neglect to protect the singleton against copying.  
See: boost::noncopyable.

Comment: "See boost::noncopyable", or just declare a private copy constructor and assignment operator. Yes, there are some other issues around singletons: for example, do they 'smell', are they thread-safe, are they constructed in the right sequence: I ws only trying to answer the actual question in the OP.

Comment: Oh I think I see what you mean: if it's a reference instead of a pointer, then its easier for someone make a copy of it accidentally, by forgetting to include the `&` when declaring the type of a variable, parameter, or return code to which it's assigned.

Comment: +1 good answer.  I want to add that the singleton object should be protected against copying regardless of whether you return a pointer or reference ... but I agree its much easier to accidentally copy it as a reference.

Comment: See the Meyers section on page 5 of this article (C++ In Theory: The Singleton Pattern, Part I) on the use of references: http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Cplusplus/C-plus-plus-In-Theory-The-Singleton-Pattern-Part-I/

Comment: Note that in C++11, if you are using the `auto` type to try and temporarily store a reference to your singleton (`auto instance = Singleton::getInstance();`), it will automatically use the singleton's copy constructor. You must explicitly use a reference to avoid the copy constructor (`Singleton& instance = Singleton::getInstance();`). It's recommended to privately declare your constructor, destructor, copy constructor and assignment operator and use an assertion in your copy constructor and assignment operator to watch for this case.

Answer (score 10):

I think it would be safer to return a reference, but don't forget about "copy protection" of your singleton object.

Comment: + 1 for bringing up 'copy protection'

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter aside from returning a reference implicitly guarantees that the singleton exists. (If it doesn't, you should throw an exception.)

This also ignores the advice that singletons are evil as much as globals are evil since singletons are basically globals in design pattern clothing.

Comment: I do maintain that singletons have legitimate uses, and an active developer working on varied software might well want one every decade of so.

Comment: Every use of singleton is an admission that you don't expect your code to scale in a particular direction. At least that's what I've found to be true.

MSN

Answer (score 0):

The getInstance() method returns a reference since the function-static object is initialized when the control flow is first passing its definition.Also working with a reference is better: now user can not delete the singleton’s pointer. In addition, this implementation is so simple!

```
class CKeyboard
{
public:
    static CKeyboard& GetInstance()
    {
        static CKeyboard keyboard;
        return keyboard;
    }

private:
    CKeyboard() {}
    CKeyboard(const CKeyboard&);
    CKeyboard& operator=(const CKeyboard&);
};
```

http://www.devartplus.com/3-simple-ways-to-create-singleton-in-c/